# How to set ordering for default selected value in jQuery select2 remote select box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I customized the select2 plugin to display default selected values. I applied the select2 remote select box in the session create and edit page. When I create a session and select multiple speakers from the dropdown it displayed as they are selected.

Create page:
[image]

But when I edit another field for that session then the selected speakers are not displaying in order as they inserted

Edit page:
[image]

here is my jQuery code snippet:

```
$(".jsRemoteSelectBox").each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).data("isprocessed") != "1" && $(element).attr("isprocessed") != 1) {
            $(element).data("isprocessed", "1");
            $(element).attr("isprocessed", "1");
            select2SelectedResult = [];
            if ($(element).data("defaultvalue") != undefined) {
                select2SelectedResult = $(element).data("defaultvalue");
            }
            oOptionHtml = [];
            var oTargetControl = $(element).data('targetcontrol');
            $(element).select2({
                dropdownAutoWidth: true,
                allowClear: ($(element).data('allowclear') == "True" ? true : false),
                closeOnSelect: ($(element).data('iscloseonselect') == "True" ? true : false),
                width: '100%',
                placeholder: ($(element).data('placeholder') != undefined ? $(element).data('placeholder') : "Type to search"),
                ajax:
                {
                    url: $(element).data('url'),
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            search: params.term,
                            pageResult: ($(element).data('pageresult') != undefined ? $(element).data('pageresult') : 10),
                            page: params.page,
                            notIn: (oTargetControl != undefined ? ($.isArray($("#" + oTargetControl).val()) ? $("#" + oTargetControl).val().join(",") : $("#" + oTargetControl).val()) : ($(element).data('fixedvalue') != undefined ? $(element).data('fixedvalue') : ""))
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, params) {
                        params.page = params.page || 1;

                        return {
                            results: data.items,
                            pagination: {
                                more: (params.page * ($(element).data('pageresult') != undefined ? $(element).data('pageresult') : 10)) < data.total_count
                            }
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
                minimumInputLength: ($(element).data('minlength') != undefined ? $(element).data('minlength') : 3),
                //templateResult: formatResult,
                templateResult: function (optionResult) {
                    if (optionResult.loading) return optionResult.text;
                    oOptionHtml = [];
                    oOptionHtml.push("<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>");
                    if ($(element).data("isimagedisplay") == "True") {
                        oOptionHtml.push("<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'>");
                        oOptionHtml.push("<img src='" + optionResult.imageurl + "' />");
                        oOptionHtml.push("</div>");
                    }
                    oOptionHtml.push("<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>");
                    oOptionHtml.push("<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>");
                    oOptionHtml.push(optionResult.full_name);
                    oOptionHtml.push("</div>");
                    oOptionHtml.push("</div>");
                    if ($(element).data("isdescriptiondisplay") == "True") {
                        oOptionHtml.push("<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>");
                        oOptionHtml.push(optionResult.description);
                        oOptionHtml.push("</div>");
                    }
                    oOptionHtml.push("</div>");

                    return oOptionHtml.join(" ");
                },
                templateSelection: formatResultSelection,
                data: select2SelectedResult
            });
            if (select2SelectedResult.length > 0) {
                $(element).val(select2SelectedResult.select('x.id'));
                $(element).trigger('change');
            }
        }
    });
```

Generated Html code on create page is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Select Speaker</label>

        <select class="jsRemoteSelectBox form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-allowclear="True" data-iscloseonselect="True" data-isdescriptiondisplay="False" data-isimagedisplay="True" data-minlength="3" data-pageresult="10" data-placeholder="Type to search speaker" data-targetcontrol="jsClientID" data-url="/Speakers/SearchSpeakers" id="SpeakerIDs" multiple="" name="SpeakerIDs" isprocessed="1" data-select2-id="SpeakerIDs" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        </select>
        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="6" style="width: 100%;">
            <span class="selection">
                <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">
                    <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                        <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                            <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Type to search speaker" style="width: 1238px;">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
        <div>
            <small>Usage: Enter at least three characters to get speakers name suggestions. Select a value to continue adding more speakers.</small>
        </div>

        <span class="field-validation-valid red" data-valmsg-for="SpeakerIDs" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Generated Html code on Edit page is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Select Speaker</label>

        <select class="jsRemoteSelectBox form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-allowclear="True" data-defaultvalue="[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Angela  Xavier (Senior Exclusive Head)&quot;,&quot;ImageUrl&quot;:&quot;cf0fab51-84af-43b6-9c4b-7e96227f4e95_images.jpg&quot;,&quot;SessionID&quot;:1056},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Jon Patel ()&quot;,&quot;ImageUrl&quot;:&quot;7844b969-e793-4af3-899c-0d28bc97da18_download_(2).png&quot;,&quot;SessionID&quot;:1056},{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Haresh Yadav ()&quot;,&quot;ImageUrl&quot;:&quot;28937477-3e2d-4166-aad8-758ffe6ad17b_Beacon_logo_FINAL_white_&amp;_green.jpg&quot;,&quot;SessionID&quot;:1056}]" data-iscloseonselect="True" data-isdescriptiondisplay="False" data-isimagedisplay="True" data-minlength="3" data-pageresult="10" data-placeholder="Type to search speaker" data-targetcontrol="jsClientID" data-url="/Speakers/SearchSpeakers" id="SpeakerIDs" multiple="" name="SpeakerIDs" isprocessed="1" data-select2-id="SpeakerIDs" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value="2" data-select2-id="17">Angela  Xavier (Senior Exclusive Head)</option>
            <option value="1" data-select2-id="18">Jon Patel ()</option>
            <option value="3" data-select2-id="19">Haresh Yadav ()</option>
        </select>
        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="16" style="width: 100%;">
            <span class="selection">
                <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">
                    <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
                        <span class="select2-selection__clear" title="Remove all items" data-select2-id="23">×</span>
                        <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Angela  Xavier (Senior Exclusive Head)" data-select2-id="20">
                            <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Angela  Xavier (Senior Exclusive Head)
                        </li>
                        <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Jon Patel ()" data-select2-id="21">
                            <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Jon Patel ()
                        </li>
                        <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Haresh Yadav ()" data-select2-id="22">
                            <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Haresh Yadav ()
                        </li>
                        <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
                            <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
        <div>
            <small>Usage: Enter at least three characters to get speakers name suggestions. Select a value to continue adding more speakers.</small>
        </div>

        <span class="field-validation-valid red" data-valmsg-for="SpeakerIDs" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: This issue is the server? or you face the issue in the local machine as well?

Comment: @jishansiddique, I am facing this issue on the server only. It is working fine on the local machine

Comment: Okay Harvi Patel have you create a select2 helper in MVC? I can see it in the edit history.

Comment: Yes @jishansiddique, I created a select2 helper in MVC. Is there any issue with that helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you need to add one `Sequence` field in the model.

Your model should be like this.

```
public string id { get; set; } // id for drop-down value
public string text { get; set; } // text for drop-down text visible in select control
public int? Sequence { get; set; } // this is the new filed you have to manage when you select multiple option in drop-down and store in db level.
```

after then need to change you're `select2 partial helper`

```
if (Model.DefaultSelectedValue != null && Model.DefaultSelectedValue.Count > 0)
{
        HtmlAttributes.Add("data-defaultValue", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.DefaultSelectedValue.OrderBy(x=>x.Sequence),
        Formatting.Indented));
}
```

Note: I've also built the same `select2 helper` but not much like you and I also facing the issue while inserting if I'm select value like `2,5,1,4` while edit values show `1,2,4,5`.

**if you still face the issue let me know so we can connect.**

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. I also made some changes to the select2 plugin according to your suggestion.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

its not an easier solution, here a sample showing what you want (event on select selecting, unselect unselecting):

```js
$('#example').select2();

$('#example').on("select2:selecting select2:unselecting", function (evt) {
    var _id = evt.params.args.data._resultId.match(/select2-(\w+)-result/)[1];
    var ul = $(`ul#select2-${_id}-container`)
    var tmpord = ul.children('li').map((idx, elm) => CSS.escape(elm.title)).get()
    tmpord.push(CSS.escape(evt.params.args.data.text))
    ul.data('tmpord', tmpord)
}).on("select2:select select2:unselect", function (evt) {
    var _id = evt.params.data._resultId.match(/select2-(\w+)-result/)[1];
    var ul = $(`ul#select2-${_id}-container`);
    ;(ul.data('tmpord')||[]).forEach(tp => {
        var li = ul.children(`li[title="${tp}"]:contains("${tp}")`)
        li.detach().appendTo(ul)
    })
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Bat">Bat</option>
    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="Elephant">Elephant</option>
    <option value="View/Exposure">View/Exposure</option>
    <option value="View / Exposure">View / Exposure</option>
    <option value="Dummy - Data">Dummy - Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy-Data">Dummy-Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy:Data">Dummy:Data</option>
    <option value="Dummy(Data)">Dummy(Data)</option>    
</select>

  </body>
</html>
```

it is using the internal undocumented _resultId property
its a hack, there's no guarantee this property will always be there

a solution with data from json or array:

```js
    var sampleArray = [
    {id: 0, text: 'enhancement'},
    {id: 1, text: 'bug'},
    {id: 2, text: 'duplicate'},
    {id: 3, text: 'invalid'},
    {id: 4, text: 'wontfix'}];

    $("#e10").select2({
      data: sampleArray
    });
    
        $('#e10').on("select2:selecting select2:unselecting", function(evt) {
      var _id = evt.params.args.data._resultId.match(/select2-(\w+)-result/)[1];
      var ul = $(`ul#select2-${_id}-container`)
      var tmpord = ul.children('li').map((idx, elm) => CSS.escape(elm.title)).get()
      tmpord.push(CSS.escape(evt.params.args.data.text))
      ul.data('tmpord', tmpord)
    }).on("select2:select select2:unselect", function(evt) {
      var _id = evt.params.data._resultId.match(/select2-(\w+)-result/)[1];
      var ul = $(`ul#select2-${_id}-container`);;
      (ul.data('tmpord') || []).forEach(tp => {
        var li = ul.children(`li[title="${tp}"]:contains("${tp}")`)
        li.detach().appendTo(ul)
      })
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="e10" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Frenchy for your help. This is not working for me because I'm not getting the _resultId property on `select2:select select2:unselect` event

Comment: could you show your html code with select and you are using the last version of select2?

Comment: i show a second sample with data from array or json, not from select and the result is the same with input type hidden

Comment: Your second sample code is the same as the first one so this is not working. I also added the HTML code in question. I am using Select2 4.0.11 version.

Comment: no its  not te same, second use input for data from array or json, the first have options defined in html. So i dont understant how your html is generated could you show your html generated before intilialization of select2?

Comment: I added generated Html code for create and HTML page. Can you please check that?